# how to use if to ignore the institution which did not appear and execute the rest command

Tags: loops, if-statement, conditional-statements, stata

I have a question on looping in Stata.

I have multiple institutions: the variable `school_code` indicates their IDs and is in the range 1 to 10000. But some codes do not appear in the data.

So I need a conditional command, `if` for example, to help me to ignore those institutions which do not appear in a given year.

Comment: The question is vague and includes no examples of (attempts to use) code. The underlying problem may be an attempt to loop over 1 to 10000 when some of those values do not occur in the data. See http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/try-all-values-with-foreach/index.html for one bundle of techniques. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for how to ask a good question.

Comment: Hi Nick, thank you for your response. My attempted code is as following:forvalue i=1(1)10000{ 
  use file4_1980_taiwan.dta, clear
  gen flagHost=(school_code==`i')
  bysort ut: egen flag2Host=sum(flagHost)
  drop if flag2Host==0
  capture confirm variable school_code
  if _rc==0{
  bysort school_code: egen count=count(school_code)
  duplicates drop school_code, force
  keep school_code count
  gen host=`i'
  gen year=1980
  save `i'_1980_temp.dta, replace
  }
}

Comment: Please edit your question; code presented like that is almost unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

The most direct way is to eliminate from your dataset (or from a copy of your dataset) the observations for which school_code is not in the range of 1 to 10000.

```
drop if ! inrange(school_code,1,10000)
```

should do this.

Alternatively, you can apply the if clause to individual commands

```
regress y x1 x2 x3 if inrange(school_code,1,10000)
```

Comment: Although this can be good technique, my guess is that the OP's problem is different.